# theme taxonomy term object

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I created a module that looks up some taxonomy terms using taxonomy_get_tree() does some stuff with it and then passes it to a template file.
In that template file i want to display them sorted according to some parameters.

The sorting stuff and all works fine but in the end i would just like to display the term using its standard template. But i can't get this to work, i have the entire term object and what i thought i had to do was something like:

```
theme('node', array('elements' => array('#view_mode' => 'teaser', '#node' => $term)));
```

but the array needs a lot more items then i can provide, so isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing 'node' as the `$hook` value, although your data is for a taxonomy term rather than a node. Trying using the hook 'taxonomy_term' instead of 'node'. I'm not sure what the proper structure for the `$variables` array is, but if you have the full term object, I would try just passing `$term` as the second parameter.

documentation for theme()
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7

documentation for theme_taxonomy_term()
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--theme.php/function/theme_taxonomy_term/7